# Help with view filters

Tags: views

I have a view using one content type: fee_schedule
The view contains fields for species, keywords (hidden), and the title.

The filters need to show ALL species except when searching by keywords.  The keywords field and the title field are combined using Global Combine fields filter that is exposed.

Here's the issue:  When someone uses the exposed species drop down, it works as expected.  It shows the 'All' species and which ever species they selected.  But when they put in keywords (like 'bulk') then it still shows All species (even though these species do not have 'bulk' as a keyword), along with the species that do have the keyword 'bulk'.  When searching using keywords, I need the view to display ONLY the species with the keyword.  When searching by species, I need it to show the content with All species and the specific species they selected.

Here's the link to the view: https://vdl-dev.umn.edu/services-fees

I am using and/or filtering as follows:

Content Published: yes AND
Content Type: Fee Schedule AND
Global Combined fields filter exposed (title and keywords) AND
Content Species (each specific species but not All)

OR

Content Species (All is only selected)

Maybe I can't do what I need to do using views.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like all filters need to be AND. Otherwise you need faceted search.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very confusing, I hope I was able to understand your problem in the end.

You've framed it as if you're applying the exposed filters and then looking at the views results. But in the end you're looking back at the Exposed filters.

The module that can help you is [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters).

> you get dynamic dependent filters, that is, when the value of one filter is changed, the list of options of the selective filters are updated accordingly to the trimmed down result set.